# Responsive Image picture media size not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

style01

```
<figure>
        <picture>
          <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg">
          <img src="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg" class="visible-md visible-lg">
          <img src="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg" class="visible-xs visible-sm">
        </picture>
        <figcaption class="blind">{{item.main_visual_desc}}</figcaption>
      </figure>
```

======================================================================

style02

```
<figure>
        <picture>
          <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg">
          <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg">
          <img src="./../../../assets/image/visual/main_visual01_m.jpg" style="width:auto">
        </picture>
        <figcaption class="blind">{{item.main_visual_desc}}</figcaption>
      </figure>
```

=======================================================================

my header

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>팝스애플 공방</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/app.component.compact.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="popsapple_favicon.ico" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

It's working on Chrome, but not working on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a nice [class](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp) which automatically renders you images as responsive images.